# IONIC 4 add css attributes to ionic components

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Does anyone know how to place an icon in a toggle? 
Is this even possible with the new shadow dom rules?

https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/toggle/

I have tried placing a icon element in the toggle but no succes.

Thanks,
Kelvijn

Comment: In Ionic 4 the toggles have a div called "toggle-icon" and "toggle-inner".. you could use it in css to add your icon

Comment: .toggle-inner {

  --content: url('../assets/ionicons.designerpack/ios-airplane.svg');
  content: url('../assets/ionicons.designerpack/ios-airplane.svg');

}

This does nothing but when I add  content... to the stylesheet in chrome it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to add attributes to ion components.
Confirmed by admin from the ionic slack.

Going to make my own slider then.